# Any way to auto-approve requests to join Facebook group?

Tags: facebook, facebook-groups, google-chrome-extensions, automation, userscripts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to make Facebook group open for joining?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10247/how-to-make-facebook-group-open-for-joining)

I run a group on Facebook and I get bombarded with requests to join it.  I just want to allow anyone to join without me having to approve them.  The "Members must be approved by an admin" checkbox on the Edit Group page is unchecked, and the Privacy is set to:

> Open - Anyone can see the group, who's in it, and what members post.

Is there any Greasemonkey script that will go through all the 'Add' buttons in the list of membership requests and press them all?

I currently have 243 requests to join and I do not want to manually approve all of them.

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/10247/how-to-make-facebook-group-open-for-joining

Comment: @mark4o I was going to reply with the same thing, minus the link. +1 for your comment.