# How to disable " [member] asked to join [group]" Facebook notifications?

Tags: facebook, notifications, facebook-groups

When you are admin of a Facebook group, you have to approve each member that wants to enter the group. In addition, you are notified every time someone asks for approval. 
If you are admin of a large group, this can cause a significant amount of useless notifications, but I can't seem to find a way to disable them. They don't appear in the "all notifications" panel, and the notification menu doesn't seem to be listing specific notification types anymore. Setting the "notification for this group" to "off" doesn't help either.

Is there a way to disable the notifications that appear when someone want to join a closed Facebook group where you have admin rights?

Answer (score 0):

From Facebook's point of view, this is a feature, not a bug. FB wants group admins to deal with members ASAP. Your main options are:

(edit: open groups have the same approval issues as closed ones)

1. change it to a **page** so people can join without approval.
2. change it to a secret group so people can't request to join.
3. give up your admin role and have someone else deal with it.

See also: [Any way to auto-approve requests to join new-style Facebook group?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24524/any-way-to-auto-approve-requests-to-join-new-style-facebook-group)

Comment: As it turns out, the problem also exists with open groups. The difference between open and closed is that non-members can see the posts in the group, but it doesn't change the membership process: you still need to manually approve each request, and you always get notified.